# Best way to represent numbers of unbounded length?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, numbers, compression

What's the most optimal (space efficient) way to represent integers of unbounded length?

(The numbers range from zero to *positive-infinity*)

Some sample number inputs can be found [here](http://ge.tt/1SxHKCe) (each number is shown on it's own line).

Is there a *compression algorithm* that is specialized in compressing numbers?

Comment: Yes, it's the identity function. It provides optimal compression of random sequences, which is 1:1.

Comment: @rici What do you mean by the identity function?

Comment: The function which returns its argument without transforming it. Faq on (not being able to) compress random data: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/compression-faq/part1/section-8.html, which compares it to perpetual motion machines.

Comment: @rici: You are right if you have infinitely many random numbers. In any other case, you can compress the set of random numbers. If you have, e.g. only a single random number that is by chance 1, i.e. 00000...0001, then you can compress it e.g. by run length encoding, which says you have m zeroes followed by n ones.

Comment: If the data is truly random it will be impossible to make it smaller *on average*. See [information theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory).

Comment: @Pacerier The obvious reason why it can't have a smaller output _on average_ is that there is no redundancy with bit strings--every bit string represents a unique number. If you have a compression algorithm that takes any number from zero to positive infinity and you map it to some bit string... well all you've done is rearrange the original mapping which maps 0 -> 0, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 10, 3 -> 11, etc. It can't possibly be more space efficient because we've assumed a uniform distribution. To be formal, you can use contradiction to show why it's impossible.

Comment: pacerier, I'm perfectly aware what the definition of compression is. Read the link I posted.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner: an infinite input can only be compressed to an infinite output, unless you know the algorithm by which the input is generated. So that requirement makes no sense at all. Given any compression algorithm, some random inputs will have shorter outputs and some will have longer outputs, but the average will never be less than 1. The identity function is, therefore, optimal.

Comment: @pacerier: of course, you can compress the ascii representation of random numbers, for example by using binary output. You might want to have asked "what's the optimal representation for integers of unbounded length?"

Comment: @rici, Yes that is right.

Comment: @Pacerier: Ok, I provided some kind of answer and fixed the title.

Comment: @MarkRansom "If the data is truly random it will be impossible to make it smaller on average". That is a very ignorant statement! You can compress numbers from a random distribution to the entropy of the distribution.

Comment: @ElKamina, the question as originally worded was about random numbers. With no details about what makes the numbers random, I naturally assume they have very high entropy since that's one of the defining characteristics of random numbers. Certainly there can be specific samples that are compressible, but the comment above makes it clear that they're interested in average compression, which will suffer due to the overhead inherent in any practical compression scheme.

Comment: @MarkRansom FYI, all random distributions can be compressed to their entropy. There are very **few** cases where you cannot compress (AKA uniform distribution). I do get what you are saying though. The OP did not define the distribution of his numbers. So we can assume that it is a uniform distribution (from 0 to infinity, which is a very 'inconvenient' distribution), which we can never compress. If the numbers were from, say, a poisson distribution we can compress.

Comment: @ElKamina: "that is a very ignorant statement" is not a particularly useful way to conduct a discussion, particularly when you later admit that the statement in question was actually reasonable.

Comment: @rici Yes. I should have probably used the adjective "uninformed". Unfortunately I cannot edit it now.

Answer (score 3):

You've basically got two alternatives for variable-length integers:

1. Use 1 bit of every `k` as an end terminator. That's the way Google protobuf does it, for example (in their case, one bit from every byte, so there are 7 useful bits in every byte).
2. Output the bit-length first, and then the bits. That's how ASN.1 works, except for OIDs which are represented in form 1.

If the numbers can be really big, Option 2 is better, although it's more complicated and you have to apply it recursively, since you may have to output the length of the length, and then the length, and then the number. A common technique is to use a Option 1 (bit markers) for the length field.

For smallish numbers, option 1 is better. Consider the case where most numbers would fit in 64 bits. The overhead of storing them 7 bits per byte is 1/7; with eight bytes, you'd represent 56 bits. Using even the 7/8 representation for length would also represent 56 bits in eight bytes: one length byte and seven data bytes. Any number shorter than 48 bits would benefit from the self-terminating code.

"Truly random numbers" of unbounded length are, on average, infinitely long, so that's probably not what you've got. More likely, you have some idea of the probability distribution of number sizes, and could choose between the above options.

Note that none of these "compress" (except relative to the bloated ascii-decimal format). The asymptote of `log n/n` is 0, so as the numbers get bigger the size of the size of the numbers tends to occupy no (relative) space. But it still needs to be represented somehow, so the total representation will always be a bit bigger than log<sub>2</sub> of the number.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compress per se, but you can encode, which may be what you're looking for.  You have files with sequences of ASCII decimal digits separated by line feeds.  You should simply Huffman encode the characters.  You won't do much better than about 3.5 bits per character.